# PHP can't show data from my database

Tags: php, database

Right now my database is connected to my php file, but the problem is, it doesn't show if I try to show any data from my database.

I want to show "username" and "voornaam" from my database.
I've been trying different things in the past hours, this is my last resort.

I attached a picture of my database.[image]
This is my code so far:

```
$conn = mysqli_connect($host, $username, $password, $database ) 
or die("verbinding mislukt: ". mysqli_connect_error());

$result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM NAW");

    echo "<table border='1'>
    <tr>
    <th>Firstname</th>
    <th>Lastname</th>
    </tr>";

    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
    {
    echo "<tr>";
    echo "<td>" . $row['username'] . "</td>";
    echo "<td>" . $row['voornaam'] . "</td>";
    echo "</tr>";
    }
    echo "</table>";

    mysqli_close($con);
```

Comment: Are you *absolutely sure* neither MySQL nor PHP are logging errors?  I suspect you haven't even bothered to check...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error is, that you wrote `$conn` instead of `$con` in your first line.

Comment: Ohhhhhhhh, thanks man!! what a STUPID MISTAKE...

Answer (score 0):

- Don't quote your table name in your query.
- Your connection variable is `$conn` and not `$con`.

```
$result = mysqli_query($conn,"SELECT * FROM NAW");
```

If you wish to use "quotes", use the back tick (`). The back tick is also required if you use reserved words as within your design.

It may be worthwhile to get into the habit of using [**`mysqli->errno`**](https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.errno.php) and [**`mysqli->error`**](https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.error.php) in the future.

Comment: Ah yes thanks that was one of the things I tried, but that didn't solve the problem.

Comment: Ah, your connection variable is actually `$conn` and not `$con`